# list of the variable names inside array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have an array that contains a set of arrays, I want to reach the inside arrays variable names like;

```
     var mainArr = [
             arr1 = ["1","2","3"],
             arr2 = ["4","5","6"],
             arr3 = ["7","8","9"],
                   ];
```

I want to print arr1, arr2, arr3.

Note that I'm using Javascript Ecma 5

Comment: You could use objects if you want key value pairs. Otherwise `mainArr[0]`, `mainArr[1]` and `mainArr[2]` will get you elements on each index.

Comment: This isn't correct way of creating a 2D Array. it should be something like 

var mainArr  = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]] and then you can access element of array using it's index.

Comment: I dont know if it is ES5 where you can call your object as mainArr['arr1'] if so you can call your array dynamically like mainArr['arr' + index]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is actually a JavaScript Object.

```
const obj = {
    arr1: ['1','2','3'],
    arr2: ['4','5','6'],
    arr3: ['7','8','9']
}
```

You can access "properties" of this object like `obj['arr1']` etc.

To get property names you can use:
`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`. It'll return an array of keys (`['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3']`).

Comment: I don't want the values, I want the variable names, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to store each array inside mainArr as an object like `{arr1: ["1","2","3"]}`.

And after you can loop through mainArr and print the key value of each element, like.

```
mainArr = [
 {arr1: ["1","2","3"]},
 {arr2: ["4","5","6"]},
 {arr3: ["7","8","9"]},
];
mainArr.forEach(arr => console.log(Object.keys(arr)))
```

This will print all arrays inside the mainArr.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually handling it the wrong way. The best way to do this by not pushing an array using Array.push() method. instead do this by using named indexed Array, because by default arrays have index as numbers i.e., 0,1,2,3,..

```
var myArray = [];

myArray["arr1"] = ["1","2","3"];

myArray["arr2"] = ["4","5","6"];

myArray["arr3"] = ["7","8","9"];

console.log(myArr); => 
 [arr1: Array(3), arr2: Array(3), arr3: Array(3)]
   arr1: (3) ["1", "2", "3"]
   arr2: (3) ["4", "5", "6"]
   arr3: (3) ["7", "8", "9"]    

console.log(Object.keys(myArray)); => ["arr1","arr2","arr3"]
```